# How do you easily check if something is in a list?

Tags: python

I basically have to print true or false if the name 'Riley' is in my list...
This is what I have:

```
if 'Riley' ??? names3:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: You have it in your post `in`.

Comment: I think you want `if 'Riley' in names3:`  http://www.jworks.nl/2013/11/07/python-goodness-the-in-keyword/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `in` keyword.

```
>>> names = ['Will', 'Dodd', 'Harry']
>>> print 'Will' in names
True
>>> print 'Barry' in names
False
```